# templateUrl not working in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a product-list.component.ts as this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    templateUrl: 'app/products/product-list.component.html'
})

export class ProductListComponent {

}
```

app.component.ts:

```
 import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ProductListComponent } from './products/product-list.component';

@NgModule({
       bootstrap:    [ ],
       imports: [ ProductListComponent],
       schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
       declarations: [AppComponent,ProductListComponent ],

})

@Component({
selector: 'pm-app',
template: `
    <div>
        <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
        <pm-products></pm-products>
    </div>
`
})

   export class AppComponent { 
pageTitle: string = 'Acme Product Management';
}
```

I used of pm-app in index.html but product-list.component.html don't appear in screen.

thanks in advance!

Comment: any error you are getting ?

Comment: do you get 404 on console?

Comment: no, all things is ok! and not get me any error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `templateUrl` should be:

```
templateUrl: './app/products/product-list.component.html'
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your `app.component.ts` as below :

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { ProductListComponent } from './products/product-list.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-app',
  template: `
    <div>
        <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
        <pm-products></pm-products>
    </div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent { 
  pageTitle: string = 'Acme Product Management';
}

@NgModule({
   bootstrap:    [AppComponent ],
   imports: [ BrowserModule ],
   declarations: [AppComponent,ProductListComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! but don't work! that's mean all things is OK! and I don't get error but product-list.component don't appear in browser!

Comment: are you getting `pageTitle` value in browser ?

Comment: check after changing `templateUrl` in `ProductListComponent` from `templateUrl: 'app/products/product-list.component.html` to `templateUrl: './product-list.component.html`

Comment: I changed that! but it's same.